# Which search method should I use?

Tags: 7, search

I want to add search option to my site but I can't decide what I should use.

I am building a news site. It has a simple structure but in time there will be lot of indexed page. When somebody use the search box, they can search inside news, the categories of the news, and the authors of the news.
The search result page should show all of them like 3 blocks as in this screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

I tried the Search API, but it doesn't provide these.

What should I use? Can you please give me some links for tutorials/documentations. How can I do that?

To make it cleaar, when I type "Marvel" in the search box, the result should include all nodes containing *marvel* and all tags including *marvel* (e.g. *marvel's movies*, *marvel's show*). I try to show two different blocks per node and tags in the search result page.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the search you can use the [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) module, this module adds options to select:

- which content type(s) to search,
- which specific module search to use (node, help, user or any module that implements search),
- which input type to use (with Elements),
- advanced criteria

And if you want modify the search result page you can modify the tpl file `search-result.tpl.php`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try Custon Search module but it not fit my needs. I cant search inside my tags. I can search (filter) my content according to tags but tag itself i can't search.

Comment: @sharktale can you provide me one example? I can't get the point

Comment: Of course. When you type "Marvel" to the searchbox result should be all contents include marvel keyword. And plus that, all tags include marvel keyword (marvel's movies, marvel's show etc.). I try to show two diffirent blocks for content and tags in search result page. I forgot to add wireframe to the post => http://i58.tinypic.com/2nvz8eg.jpg